# Why DT_WSTR not match nvarchar data type for ssis fuzzy grouping

Tags: ssis, grouping, fuzzy

I try to use ssis `fuzzy grouping` to identify duplicates. The package is simple
[image: ssis fuzzy grouping]

The data source is `sql server 2016` and [image: **data type is DT_WSTR**]

When I run the package I got the following error message:

> [Fuzzy Grouping Inner Data Flow : Fuzzy Lookup [49]] Error: The fuzzy
>   lookup specified between input column "Column1" and reference column
>   "[Column1]" is not valid because fuzzy joins are only supported
>   between string columns, types DT_STR and DT_WSTR.

I inserted[image: **derived column**] to change the data types but I got same error.

Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are still not using **derived column1** as a source column ,use **derived column1** this instead of **Adress1_Line1** in destination mapping.

You can also use `Data Conversion Task` instead of `derived column`,please check after using `data conversion task`.
I hope you will not get error.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. I use `select cast(coalesce([Address1_Line1], '') as nvarchar (4000)) as address1 from [TableName]` in OLE DB source.
Got the following error message: "The size (4002) given to the parameter 'Column0' exceeds the maximum allowed (4000).".

Step 2. `alter table TableName alter column Address1_Line1 nvarchar (1000)`
and the package runs successful without derived column or data conversion task.

The issue is nvarchar(4000) is different than SSIS maximum allowed 4000 **Bites**